# Counterexample Banach-Steinhaus

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a problem solving following:
Its a Counterexample to Banach-Steinhaus. Its bounded for every point but not uniformly

We have $X=C^0 (I), ||.||_{L^2}$ with $I = [0,1]$
$||f||_{L^2}= (\int_I |f(t)|^2 dt) ^{1/2}$

Now there are linear Operators $T_n = n \int_0^{1/n} f(t) dt$

with $T_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

So we have to show that  $sup||Tx||<\infty$  is true but
$sup||T||<\infty$ isnt.

I dont even know how to begin here

Sorry i missed the "n" in $T_n$.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Begin by stating the problem correctly... If $T_n$ is as above then $||T_n||\to0$.

Comment: The question is, why is it bounded but not uniformly bounded? $T_n$ is exactly what i posted.

Comment: The definition of $T_n$ does not make sense. If $T_nf = \int_0^{1/n}f(t)dt$, then $|T_nf| \le \|f\|_{L^2}$, hence the $T_n$ are uniformly bounded...

Comment: You are right, my bad. Its $T_n = n \int_0^{1/n} f(t) dt$

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523919/banach-steinhaus-and-sequence-of-functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Banach-Steinhaus and sequence of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523919/banach-steinhaus-and-sequence-of-functions)

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n$ is $n^{1/2}$ on (0,1/n), 0 on (2/n,] and linear inbetween then $f_n$'s are bounded in $L^2$ norm and $T_n f_n$ is unbounded. These functiosn do not vanish at 0 but it is easy to modify this example so that the new functions vanish at 0.

Comment: I guess i have to show that its in general bounded for all $f_n$ and then pick an example its uniformly unbounded. I know that f is bounded (compact and continous on [0,1]). issue is i dont see the counter example. $sup||T_n||=( \int_I (n \int_0^{1/n} n^{1/2})^2  dt)^{1/2} $